# Regex to find all month and years in a dataframe

Tags: r

Having a dataframe in this structure:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), date1 = c("2014-Dec 2018","2009-2010","Jan 2009-Aug 2010"), date2 = c("Feb 2016-Dec 2018","2014-Dec 2018","Oct 2013-Dec 2018"))
```

How is it possible to form a regex to find all months and years and keep them in a different dataframe?

Example of this option

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(!if_all(!id, ~ grepl('^[A-Z][a-z]{2}\\s+', .x)))
id             date1             date2
1  1     2014-Dec 2018 Feb 2016-Dec 2018
2  2 Jan 2009-Aug 2010     2014-Dec 2018
```

Comment: What is the exact output you want?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I added an example. The form of months is the same (three first letters)